# How can I programmatically include meta tags in the DNN header tags?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dotnetnuke, dnn9

I would like to use a string writer to add meta tags dynamically in the header tag of my DNN site.

I am not sure if I can use the DNNPageHeaderProvider to achieve this?

[image]

Or should I do something like the example below?
[image]

This is the facebook Open-Graph meta tags I would like to add.

```
<header>

...

<!-- Open Graph Metadata -->

 <meta property="og:title" content="Facebook T-Shirt">

 <meta property="og:description" content="Unisex Facebook T-shirt, Small">

 <meta property="og:url" content="https://example.org/facebook">

 <meta property="og:image" content="https://example.org/facebook.jpg">

 <meta property="product:brand" content="Facebook">

 <meta property="product:availability" content="in stock">

 <meta property="product:condition" content="new">

 <meta property="product:price:amount" content="9.99">

 <meta property="product:price:currency" content="USD">

 <meta property="product:retailer_item_id" content="facebook_tshirt_001">

<!-- End Open Graph Metadata -->

...

</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found the answer.

You can use Attribute.Add to add a property to HtmlMeta()

```
HtmlMeta OpenGraphBrand = new HtmlMeta();
OpenGraphBrand.Attributes.Add("property", "product:brand");
OpenGraphBrand.Content = "Our Brand";
Page.Header.Controls.Add(OpenGraphBrand);
```

[ASP.NET Change facebook og properties from content page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554749/asp-net-change-facebook-og-properties-from-content-page)

Comment: I wrote a SkinObject to add OpenGraph properties to a page. It is free in the DNN store: https://store.dnnsoftware.com/home/product-details/opengraph

Comment: @VDWWD This is really cool. I guess this can be used for static content only as we have to submit OpenGraph properties for different products. Thanks for the assistance, I will definitely check this out.

Comment: The module does load the title dynamically. But if you are talking about products in a shop then no, this version does not support that. If it is a widely used shop-module i can try and intergrate it. The problem is as you say the dynamic data. Which product image to use, which product description etc.

Comment: @VDWWD We built our own shopping module which integrates with our own ERP system. Thanks for the help. I will use this module for our other pages.